# Filtering objects in ListView by Date - Django

Tags: python, django

So, in my project there is a listview in which i would like to show the objects containing only the current date, i am using the datetime module and overwriting of the getquery method, but the view has been showing all the elements no matter what date.

## View

```
date = datetime.date.today()

class AppointmentIndexView(ListView):
    model = Consults
    template_name = 'appointments_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'consults'
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset  = super().get_queryset()
        queryset.filter(Fecha=date)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the filtered queryset.

```
class AppointmentIndexView(ListView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset  = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(Fecha=date)
```

Because when you run `.filter(...)`, it will return a queryset from `filter` function. You can either store it in a variable like `q = queryset.filter(...)` or directly return it like above example.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, your problem is that `queryset.filter()` will not update your original queryset.  So when you return the queryset, you'r actually returning the original version, not the filtered one.

Try this:

```
date = datetime.date.today()

class AppointmentIndexView(ListView):
    model = Consults
    template_name = 'appointments_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'consults'
    paginate_by = 7

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(Fecha=date)
```

Also, in Django you should use the timezone aware date/time.

```
from django.utils import timezone
date = timezone.localdate()
```